# Wrong answer in C for long number calculations

Tags: c, long-integer

```
long int k=(long int)(2000*2000*2000);
```

the above calculation is giving me wrong answer in C. What is wrong?

Comment: long int is not enough to hold 2000*2000*2000. Use long long int.

Comment: Well, how big is 2000*2000*2000?

Answer (score 3):

If a C integer constant fits in an `int`, it is of type `int`. So your expression is evaluated as:

```
long int k = (long int)((int)2000*(int)2000*(int)2000);
```

If `int` isn't large enough to hold the result of the multiplication, you'll get a signed integer overflow and undefined behavior. So if `long` is large enough to hold the result, you should write:

```
long k = 2000L * 2000L * 2000L;
```

The `L` suffix forces the type of the literal to `long` (`long` is equivalent to `long int`).

But on most platforms, even `long` is only a 32-bit type, so you have to use `long long` which is guaranteed to have at least 64 bits:

```
long long k = 2000LL * 2000LL * 2000LL;
```

The `LL` suffix forces the type of the literal to `long long`.

Answer (score 2):

`2000` is of type `int`, so `2000*2000*2000` is also of type `int`.

Assuming a 32-bit `int` (which is actually more than the standard requires, since an `int` is not required by the standard to represent a value more than `32767`) the maximum representable value is about `2,147,483,647` (commas inserted for readability) which is less than `8,000,000,000`.

You will probably want to do the calcuation as `2000LL*2000*2000` which takes advantage of multiplication being left-right associative, and will promote all the `2000` values to `long long int` before doing the multiplication.   Your variable will also need to be of type `long long int` if you want a guarantee of being able to store the result.

Answer (score 1):

Holt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34289547/2411320) is the correct one, I am just leaving this here as *caveat*!

---

You *could try to* use:

`long long int`

instead of

`long int`

However, in my local machine, it has no effect:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    long int k=(long int)(2000*2000*2000);
    printf("With long int, I am getting: %ld\n", k);

    long long int n = 2000*2000*2000;
    printf("With long long int, I am getting: %lld\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
With long int, I am getting: -589934592
With long long int, I am getting: -589934592
```

Warnings:

```
../main.c:6:36: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
     long int k=(long int)(2000*2000*2000);
                                    ^
../main.c:9:32: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
     long long int n = 2000*2000*2000;
```

---

Even this:

```
unsigned long long int n = 2000*2000*2000;
printf("With long long int, I am getting: %llu\n", n);
```

will overflow too.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code:

1. `long int` is (on most architecture) not enough to store `8e9`.
2. When you do `2000 * 2000 * 2000`, operations are made using "simple" `int`, thus, `int * int * int = int` so you cast the result to an `int` and then to a `long int`.

You need to use `long long int` and specify that you want `long long int`:

```
long long int k = 2000LL*2000LL*2000LL;
```

Notice the extra `LL` after `2000` saying "It's 2000, but as a `long long int`!".

Comment: Correct!, Your answer if far better, however I will leave mine as a cave-eat.

Comment: Nowadays, a long int is 64-bit on most platforms, so it is sufficient to store this number.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just multiply the values together as ordinary precision integers and then cast the result to a higher precision, because the result has already overflowed at that point.  Instead, the operands need to be higher precision integers before they're multiplied.  Try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long int n = (long long int)2000*(long long int)2000*(long long int)2000;
    printf("long long int operands: %lld\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, this gives:

```
long long int operands: 8000000000
```